# Manifolds and magnetic potential

Tags: manifolds, mathematical-physics

Assume we have a particle in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which we will subject to different fields independently. It will have some potential energy $U\in \mathbb{R}$ defined as some constant minus its kinetic energy.

Given a conservative vector field, the potential energy $U$ is given by some function $g:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ due to the path-independence of $$\int_a^b\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}.$$

However, given a non-conservative vector field that induces an acceleration $\mathbf{F}\times\mathbf{v}$, it is not immediately obvious what the potential energy function will be given the co-ordinates*. It feels like the (speed and therefore) potential energy  will depend strongly on the 'history' of the particle (i.e. how it got to that co-ordinate as well as the co-ordinate itself). It thus seems like the potential energy function $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ will have its domain $S$ being some sort of manifold.

Is this true, and if it is or I'm not too far off, could someone help in elucidating the matter?

For simplicity, take a non-conservative field $F$ whose divergence is $0$ (e.g. $\mathbf{B}$). For a very simple example, take $\mathbf{F}=(y)\hat{\mathbf{x}}$.

---

*Obviously it's trivial to give it as a function of velocity, so assume throughout that we're looking for an $f$ .

Comment: You can shed some light on those things by observing them in the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formalism. You might want to have a look at Goldstein's book on classical mechanics, 3rd ed., pag. 55.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you, that goes some of the way to clearing up concerns about the behaviour of the potential: I haven't seen the vector potential as applied to Lagrangian mechanics yet. However, the question concerning my hunch about manifolds still stands.

Comment: I think that you will find that answer in the Lagrangian formalism too. In its global form, a Lagrangian system lives on a manifold. For that I guess that you should look into mathematics-oriented mechanics books. The standard reference (AFAIK) is Arnold's book, but I cannot be more precise unfortunately.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Arnold looks about right. I'll leave the question open as I don't think I could read Arnold very quickly.